# Is there a way to determine if a Linux PID is paused or not?

Tags: python, linux, process, controls, pid

I have a python script that is using the SIGSTOP and .SIGCONT commands with os.kill to pause or resume a process.  Is there a way to determine whether the related PID is in the paused or resumed state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find information about a process from its /proc directory (`/proc/<PID>`). Specifically, you can find its run state with this python expression:

```
open(os.path.join('/proc', str(pid), 'stat')).readline().split()[2]=='T'
```

EDIT: This next expression fixes a (presumably rare) bug with the original:

```
re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '()', open(os.path.join('/proc', str(pid), 'stat')).readline()).split()[2]=='T'
```

Comment: Not using os.path.join!... wait, this is pure linux question.

Answer (score 4):

call ps and check the STAT value.
D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.

Comment: Thank you, I used ps axo fname,stat,pid and that worked just like you said, I didn't know the STAT value was for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [psuti](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)l:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> pid = 1243
>>> p = psutil.Process(pid)
>>> p.status
0
>>> str(p.status)
'running'
>>> p.status == psutil.STATUS_RUNNING
True
>>>
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.status
3
>>> str(p.status)
'stopped'
>>> p.status == psutil.STATUS_STOPPED
True
>>>
>>> p.resume()
>>> str(p.status)
'running'
>>>
```