# PID Processes Python paused state

Tags: python, subprocess, pid

Is there a way to determine whether or not a process/PID is in a paused state or not?

Currently using `Popen("kill -STOP "+str(pid),shell=True)` to pause a process.

What is the recommended way of determining whether a given pid is in pause state or not?

Comment: May this one will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021771/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-linux-pid-is-paused-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Your can read `/proc/:pid/stat` or `/proc/:pid/status`, for example:

```
Name:   python
State:  T (stopped)
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this into my code? Not entirely sure how to use this.

Comment: Something like: `def is_paused(pid): return open("/proc/{0}/stat".format(pid)).read().split()[2] == "T"`

Comment: I get the following error.
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/2374/stat'`

Comment: So you should add exception handling, it looks like there is no process with this pid.

Comment: Is there a process which is always present? I tried the command in terminal and it always prints out that error.

Comment: There is always `init` process with pid `1`, but you shouldn't stop it, you can run python interpreter in one terminal, get pid with `os.getpid()` and experiment with it.